# Using apply() instead of iterrows on Dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have the following Dataframe, and I am trying to calculate a indicator:

```
    Date    saldo
0   2018-01-02  94.0
1   2018-01-03  92.0
2   2018-01-04  90.0
3   2018-01-06  86.0
4   2018-01-07  84.0
5   2018-01-08  82.0
6   2018-01-09  80.0
7   2018-01-11  76.0
8   2018-01-12  72.0
9   2018-01-13  70.0
```

I use iterrows approach, and it worked properly, returning the expected output.

```
data = 0
n = 0
c= 0
V=0
recompra = 35
qtd = 40
leadtime = 10

Data = []
Valor = []

for index, row in dk.iterrows():

    if (row['saldo'] + c) < recompra:
        data += 1
        V = row['saldo'] + c

    if data == leadtime:

        n += 1
        c = qtd * n
        data = 0

    else:
        V = row['saldo'] + c

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Data, Valor)), columns=['Data', 'Valor'])
```

When I tried to apply the same approach using apply(), it worked, however, it return the same output from 'saldo' column.

```
def optimize(row):
    data = 0
    n = 0
    c= 0
    recompra = 35
    qtd = 40
    leadtime = 10

    if (row['saldo'] + c) < recompra:
        data += 1
        return row['saldo'] + c

    if data == leadtime:
        n += 1
        c = (qtd) * n
        data = 0

    else:
        return row['saldo'] + c

df['Simular'] = df.apply(optimize, axis=1)
```

What I got from the second approach was a copy from the same column:

```
Date    saldo   Simulado
0   2018-01-02  94.0    94.0
1   2018-01-03  92.0    92.0
2   2018-01-04  90.0    90.0
3   2018-01-06  86.0    86.0
4   2018-01-07  84.0    84.0
5   2018-01-08  82.0    82.0
6   2018-01-09  80.0    80.0
7   2018-01-11  76.0    76.0
8   2018-01-12  72.0    72.0
9   2018-01-13  70.0    70.0
```

Comment: Where is `recompra` defined? Can you share a sample output?  Please review [mcve]

Comment: `leadtime` is not defined too

Answer (score 0):

You apply function always returns row['saldo'] + c, as data == leadtime is never true. Being c equal to 0, your code seems to be behaving correctly ; appending a copy of the column ['saldo'] as ['Simular'].

You should change your variables or your statements if you intend different results.